# How to host a angular project on Contabo Object Storage?

Tags: angular, deployment, hosting

I'm trying to migrate a deployment process that is done in S3 to Contabo Object Storage. The project is developed in angular and works fine on S3. I performed the upload using pretty much the same CI/CD code, but I couldn't find any interface to set up the static web page hosting configuration, like that existing on S3. In the documentation it says that the product is S3 compatible, so how could I do this configuration using CLI?

My current **.gitlab-ci.yml** looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-client:
  stage: build
  image: node:16.18-alpine
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - echo "Total Size:" && du -sh dist
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
  only:
    - development

deploy-client:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  dependencies:
    - build-client
  before_script:
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_SECRET_KEY
  script:
    - aws --endpoint-url $CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_URL s3 rm --recursive s3://$CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    - aws --endpoint-url $CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_URL s3 cp ./dist s3://$CONTABO_OBJECT_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME --recursive
  only:
    - development
```

I've also tried this tutorial, but I don't think it's directly related:
https://docs.contabo.com/docs/products/Object-Storage/HowTo/public-sharing